# How can I know why it crashes?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, stack-trace

My application works perfectly in my personal iphone. I sent it to the appstore and they say it crashes  while connected to a WiFi or 3G network. Does it make sense? DOnt know what to do.
This is the log

> > Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes: 0x00000000,
> >     0x00000000 Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 Crashed: 0
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bd52d4 0x33b5c000 + 496340 1
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bd52c4 0x33b5c000 + 496324 2
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bd52b6 0x33b5c000 + 496310 3
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33be9d72 0x33b5c000 + 580978 4
>   libstdc++.6.dylib
>     0x31bdba20 0x31b97000 + 281120 5
>   libobjc.A.dylib
>     0x3347c594 0x33476000 + 26004 6
>   libstdc++.6.dylib
>     0x31bd9df2 0x31b97000 + 273906 7
>   libstdc++.6.dylib
>     0x31bd9e46 0x31b97000 + 273990 8
>   libstdc++.6.dylib
>     0x31bd9f16 0x31b97000 + 274198 9
>   libobjc.A.dylib
>     0x3347b4c4 0x33476000 + 21700 10 
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a50ef2 0x33a20000 + 200434 11 
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a50d10 0x33a20000 + 199952 12 
>   balonmano
>     0x000039c4 0x1000 + 10692 13 
>   balonmano
>     0x0006522c 0x1000 + 410156 14 
>   balonmano
>     0x000024dc 0x1000 + 5340 15 
>   balonmano
>     0x0000720c 0x1000 + 25100 16 
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a6bcfc 0x33a20000 + 310524 17 
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a6bbce 0x33a20000 + 310222 18 
>   balonmano
>     0x0005f93c 0x1000 + 387388 19 
>   balonmano
>     0x0005c7c8 0x1000 + 374728 20 
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a67fe6 0x33a20000 + 294886 21 
>   balonmano
>     0x000b9a50 0x1000 + 756304 22 
>   balonmano
>     0x000ba674 0x1000 + 759412 23 
>   balonmano
>     0x000c5ba0 0x1000 + 805792 24  UIKit 
>     0x3207b34e 0x32062000 + 103246 25 
>   UIKit
>     0x3207acc8 0x32062000 + 101576 26 
>   UIKit
>     0x32065fc0 0x32062000 + 16320 27 
>   UIKit
>     0x32065900 0x32062000 + 14592 28 
>   GraphicsServices
>     0x33b0eefc 0x33b0a000 + 20220 29 
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a556f8 0x33a20000 + 218872 30 
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a556bc 0x33a20000 + 218812 31 
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a47f76 0x33a20000 + 163702 32 
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944 33 
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696 34 
>   GraphicsServices
>     0x33b0e4a4 0x33b0a000 + 17572 35 
>   GraphicsServices
>     0x33b0e550 0x33b0a000 + 17744 36 
>   UIKit
>     0x32099322 0x32062000 + 226082 37 
>   UIKit
>     0x32096e8c 0x32062000 + 216716 38 
>   balonmano
>     0x0000242c 0x1000 + 5164 39 
>   balonmano
>     0x00002398 0x1000 + 5016
>
> Thread 1: 0   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33b89974 0x33b5c000 + 186740 1
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33c33704 0x33b5c000 + 882436 2
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33c33174 0x33b5c000 + 881012 3
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33c32b98 0x33b5c000 + 879512 4
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bd724a 0x33b5c000 + 504394 5
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bcf970 0x33b5c000 + 473456
>
> Thread 2: 0   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33b5d268 0x33b5c000 + 4712 1
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33b5f354 0x33b5c000 + 13140 2
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a48648 0x33a20000 + 165448 3
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a47ed2 0x33a20000 + 163538 4
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944 5
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696 6
>   WebCore
>     0x304df124 0x30428000 + 749860 7
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894 8
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352
>
> Thread 3: 0   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bd79e0 0x33b5c000 + 506336 1
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bd7364 0x33b5c000 + 504676 2
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bcf970 0x33b5c000 + 473456
>
> Thread 4: 0   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bd79e0 0x33b5c000 + 506336 1
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bd7364 0x33b5c000 + 504676 2
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bcf970 0x33b5c000 + 473456
>
> Thread 5: 0   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33b5d268 0x33b5c000 + 4712 1
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33b5f354 0x33b5c000 + 13140 2
>   AudioToolbox
>     0x31714b96 0x3164f000 + 809878 3
>   AudioToolbox
>     0x316501d2 0x3164f000 + 4562 4
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894 5
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352
>
> Thread 6: 0   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33b5d268 0x33b5c000 + 4712 1
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33b5f354 0x33b5c000 + 13140 2
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a48648 0x33a20000 + 165448 3
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a47ed2 0x33a20000 + 163538 4
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a47c80 0x33a20000 + 162944 5
>   CoreFoundation
>     0x33a47b88 0x33a20000 + 162696 6
>   AudioToolbox
>     0x316504ba 0x3164f000 + 5306 7
>   AudioToolbox
>     0x31663306 0x3164f000 + 82694 8
>   AudioToolbox
>     0x316501d2 0x3164f000 + 4562 9
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bd6886 0x33b5c000 + 501894 10 
>   libSystem.B.dylib
>     0x33bcba88 0x33b5c000 + 457352
>
> Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread
>   State:
>       r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3eaf12e8
>       r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x31bd9989      r6: 0x0024bedc      r7: 0x2fdfdc08
>       r8: 0x3237db67    r9: 0x00000065     r10: 0x00000007     r11: 0x33479455
>       ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fdfdc08      lr: 0x33bd52cb      pc: 0x33bd52d4
>   cpsr: 0x000f0010
>
> Binary Images:
>       0x1000 -    0xeefff +balonmano armv6 
>   <9e8d6823acc4699f108a1766b1dc30e8>
>   /var/mobile/Applications/D7FD7DEB-63C6-4F24-BC83-60EFCDA2BA07/balonmano.app/balonmano
>   0x1f7000 -   0x1f8fff  dns.so armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/info/dns.so 0x2fe00000 -
>   0x2fe27fff  dyld armv7 
>   <06e6959cebb4a72e66c833e26ae64d26>
>   /usr/lib/dyld 0x30005000 - 0x30006fff 
>   CoreSurface armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
>   0x30007000 - 0x300abfff 
>   IMGSGX535GLDriver armv7 
>   <03ce082398774b1c545d08b64081d82e>
>   /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX535GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX535GLDriver
>   0x300bd000 - 0x301fafff  MediaToolbox
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
>   0x301fc000 - 0x302e4fff 
>   libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7 
>   <1f478a71783cd7eb4ae9ef6f2dcea803>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
>   0x303d1000 - 0x30426fff  libvDSP.dylib
>   armv7 
>   <9365fc6cae1bff737257e74faf3b1f26>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
>   0x30428000 - 0x30a10fff  WebCore armv7
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
>   0x30a28000 - 0x30ad5fff 
>   JavaScriptCore armv7 
>   <3f2df600942dc72aad312b3cc98ec479>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
>   0x30c98000 - 0x30d57fff  CFNetwork
>   armv7 
>   <02fe0e30e54fffdcbbbd02e8cb812c3a>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
>   0x30d58000 - 0x30d60fff  libkxld.dylib
>   armv7 
>   <854e82fe66feef01e54c7c8a209851ac>
>   /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
>   0x30d61000 - 0x30e4afff  GLEngine
>   armv7 
>   <305ddfcddb54d00acd8e2ca9005496c8>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
>   0x31266000 - 0x3129cfff  CoreText
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
>   0x313e7000 - 0x313e9fff 
>   MobileInstallation armv7 
>   <8e6b0d9f642be06729ffdaaee97053b0>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
>   0x31451000 - 0x31464fff  libmis.dylib
>   armv7 
>   <855aefc263c6c20e6cf8723ea36125a2>
>   /usr/lib/libmis.dylib 0x314ad000 -
>   0x314b8fff  libz.1.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib 0x31633000 -
>   0x31634fff  DataMigration armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
>   0x31635000 - 0x3164afff  OpenAL armv7 
>   <8ea22c729b71c6e7e19566b91a03afd2>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/OpenAL
>   0x3164f000 - 0x31788fff  AudioToolbox
>   armv7 
>   <657b327f2ceee9f22f9474f2f9bddbe6>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
>   0x317ce000 - 0x317d3fff 
>   libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7 
>   <5f73c7138ee1cb7103a98aec99f9ed88>
>   /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
>   0x31947000 - 0x3194ffff  MobileWiFi
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
>   0x31950000 - 0x31966fff  EAP8021X
>   armv7 
>   <36659ec2b9def7b5798a05327e369247>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
>   0x319b5000 - 0x319bbfff 
>   liblockdown.dylib armv7 
>   <5bbd9b3f5cfece328f80c403a8805ce9>
>   /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib 0x319d7000
>   - 0x319dafff  ApplePushService armv7  <9d1eb7b11f0f146c941efbab2c055606>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
>   0x31a3f000 - 0x31a7cfff  CoreMedia
>   armv7 
>   <4ea4d349e886206d1ecf5bae870f3f04>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
>   0x31a97000 - 0x31b2afff  ImageIO armv7
>   <5b5a294d4250eff866fdbf891b1e8b34>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
>   0x31b40000 - 0x31b80fff  CoreAudio
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
>   0x31b81000 - 0x31b96fff 
>   libresolv.9.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib 0x31b97000
>   - 0x31be1fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <53a6e7239c3908fa8c2915b65ff3b056>
>   /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib 0x31c9b000
>   - 0x31ca7fff  SpringBoardServices armv7 
>   <137b75e19b2450c234dec88d538798ff>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
>   0x31cb8000 - 0x31ceafff  AppSupport
>   armv7 
>   <47c8055ac99f187174ca373b702ffa68>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
>   0x31ceb000 - 0x31cf4fff  CoreVideo
>   armv7 
>   <2092d5deb6b234e04678b7c1878ccd81>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
>   0x31d30000 - 0x31d37fff 
>   AggregateDictionary armv7 
>   <71372c95d4af7af787d0682a939e40ac>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
>   0x31f68000 - 0x31f88fff  PrintKit
>   armv7 
>   <02a9c6f4173a0673c4637a3b570345cd>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
>   0x32059000 - 0x32061fff 
>   MobileBluetooth armv7 
>   <6d6c62f52219d27be50f1d7c39a68dc6>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
>   0x32062000 - 0x323e3fff  UIKit armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
>   0x32481000 - 0x32483fff 
>   libAccessibility.dylib armv7 
>   <3f0b58ea13d30f0cdb73f6ffe6d4e75c>
>   /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
>   0x3256d000 - 0x3261cfff  WebKit armv7 
>   <644a1c6120578f896bed7121307aa2af>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
>   0x3261e000 - 0x3262bfff 
>   libbsm.0.dylib armv7 
>   <0f4e595e6eb2170aceb729f32b5de8c2>
>   /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib 0x3262e000 -
>   0x32671fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7
>   <27ac7f05482a8aa9977150f34f9be6eb>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
>   0x32ac8000 - 0x32acafff 
>   libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib 0x32ad8000 -
>   0x32adffff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7 
>   <2989ea7a5cad2cfe91bd632b041d0ff4>
>   /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib 0x32b0a000 -
>   0x32b44fff  IOKit armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
>   0x32b45000 - 0x32b7cfff  Security
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
>   0x32bab000 - 0x32badfff 
>   IOMobileFramebuffer armv7 
>   <1040629f37795146c9dcac8ab1a868fc>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
>   0x32bae000 - 0x32e48fff 
>   libLAPACK.dylib armv7 
>   <2e77d87e96af938aacf0a6008e6fb89d>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
>   0x32e8a000 - 0x32e8dfff 
>   CaptiveNetwork armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
>   0x32f24000 - 0x32f55fff  VideoToolbox
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
>   0x32f67000 - 0x32f71fff 
>   AccountSettings armv7 
>   <19c79f81d5d55fe2e6b618fcdc28258e>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
>   0x32f72000 - 0x32f7ffff  OpenGLES
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
>   0x32fc8000 - 0x32ffbfff  AddressBook
>   armv7 
>   <7c87e0175c8649d6832419da8a1cfac1>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
>   0x32ffc000 - 0x32ffffff 
>   libGFXShared.dylib armv7 
>   <3a385ed495379116abbe50bc8cd5a612>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
>   0x331d0000 - 0x3323ffff  ProofReader
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
>   0x33393000 - 0x333defff  libBLAS.dylib
>   armv7 
>   <251c5ac7380802a16e30d827c027c637>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
>   0x333df000 - 0x333e2fff  IOSurface
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
>   0x33476000 - 0x33537fff 
>   libobjc.A.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib 0x335e8000 -
>   0x335e8fff  Accelerate armv7 
>   <29dd5f17440bbb6e8e42e11b6fceda9a>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
>   0x33619000 - 0x33738fff  Foundation
>   armv7 
>   <81d36041f04318cb51db5aafed9ce504>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
>   0x33748000 - 0x33795fff 
>   libsqlite3.dylib armv7 
>   <55038e5c1d4d0dbdd94295e8cad7a9a4>
>   /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib 0x33797000 -
>   0x337b0fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
>   0x33980000 - 0x33980fff  vecLib armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
>   0x33a20000 - 0x33b06fff 
>   CoreFoundation armv7 
>   <01441e01f5141a50ee723362e59ca400>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
>   0x33b0a000 - 0x33b16fff 
>   GraphicsServices armv7 
>   <0099670dccd99466653956bf918d667a>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
>   0x33b43000 - 0x33b48fff  MobileKeyBag
>   armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
>   0x33b5c000 - 0x33c6dfff 
>   libSystem.B.dylib armv7 
>   <138a43ab528bb428651e6aa7a2a7293c>
>   /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib 0x33c95000
>   - 0x33d36fff  Celestial armv7  
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
>   0x33d6b000 - 0x33d94fff 
>   MobileCoreServices armv7 
>   <54484a513761868149405df7fc29b5c0>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
>   0x33d95000 - 0x33d99fff 
>   AssetsLibraryServices armv7 
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
>   0x340c9000 - 0x340f8fff 
>   SystemConfiguration armv7 
>   <3f982c11b5526fc39a92d585c60d8a90>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
>   0x340f9000 - 0x341a7fff  QuartzCore
>   armv7 
>   <83a8e5f0033369e437069c1e758fed83>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
>   0x341c1000 - 0x342e1fff  CoreGraphics
>   armv7 
>   <2d7b40a7baca915ce78b1dd9a0d6433b>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
>   0x343c3000 - 0x3446cfff 
>   libxml2.2.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib 0x3451f000 -
>   0x3460cfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib 0x34613000 -
>   0x34625fff  PersistentConnection armv7
>   
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
>   0x3464e000 - 0x34764fff 
>   libicucore.A.dylib armv7 
>   
>   /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib 0x34774000
>   - 0x347b3fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
>   0x347d9000 - 0x34855fff  AVFoundation
>   armv7 
>   <4c7356c795e01bd5c21b00a409a07476>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
>   0x34867000 - 0x34886fff  Bom armv7 
>   <0f5fd6057bad5e1677869500d636821f>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
>   0x34887000 - 0x348c9fff  CoreTelephony
>   armv7 
>   <96d3af505b9f2887e62c7e99c157733e>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
>   0x348ca000 - 0x348ccfff 
>   CrashReporterSupport armv7 
>   <30a5f1edcdb9ffe868a620199a4cbe12>
>   /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should symbolicate this crashlog to see what is happening in your application. Did you save your app binary and dSYMs?

To symbolicate crashlog, you can use my way. Add following line to `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias scall="find . -name '*.crash' -exec /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash {} \;"
```

Put your application binary, dSYM and crashlogs (each crashlog in one file with .crash suffix) and call scall. It will symbolicate all your crashlogs in current directory.

Answer (score 0):

As in all debugging, the key is to isolate what is different between the application running on your iPhone and the environment in which Apple is running it.

The first thing, I would look at is that running an application in the development environment setup on your phone vs. what is the distribution environment.

Once you have a handle on that one, that will point you to where this problem is existing. It is also possible that you are hitting a difference in the version of the iOS on your system.